# Is it possible to check that int array contains only numbers 1 to 7 and no duplicates?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to ensure an attribute of type `int[]` contains maximum 7 items, and that they are unique numbers between 1 and 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `unnest()` and some aggregation with conditions:

```
select ar,
       (select count(*) = count(distinct(el)) and min(el) >= 1 and max(el) <= 7
        from unnest(v.ar) el
       ) as flag
from (values (array[1, 3, 4]),
             (array[1, 8]),
             (array[1, 1, 2])
     ) v(ar);
```

Comment: wow!  thanks!  on a side note, do you think its a good idea to put the same check on the actual create table query for that attribute?

Comment: @user1354934 . . . That might be more difficult as a `check` constraint.  I think you would have to use a user-defined function.